# Having 2 blocks of text side by side

Tags: html, css

I try to have 2 blocks of text side by side. Can you help me?

Something like this:

[image]

If the page is resized, I would like the 2 blocks to be centered. I was not able to have my blocks side by side.

I create a jsFiddle here as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/LpJBm/2/

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `float: right;` in the css for block2 ?

Comment: @Steve: You also need to swap the order of the HTML elements - see my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by centered? Do you want a fixed width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the div and wrap them to be centered: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj5Wy/

Comment: You need `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper - see my answer

Comment: It's not necessary, but probably he would run into the next problem without, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just float the gray box right:

```
#block2 {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    float: right;
}
```

And swap the order of the HTML:

```
<div id="block2">
    Nos bureaux sont ouverts du lundi au vendredi de 9h00 à 17h00
</div>
<div id="block1">
    Merci d'avoir utilisé notre plateforme...
</div>
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/LpJBm/8/

---

Centering the boxes is a separate problem. To center anything horizontally, wrap it in a div, and apply

```
.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px; /*The width you want it to be when centered*/
    /* min-width works too */
}
```

In your case, you also need `overflow: hidden`, in order to force your wrapper to contain the floats.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/LpJBm/18/
    ​

Comment: I think this is the best idea. Also give the first one a right margin and some padding to the body - like this http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/LpJBm/11/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LpJBm/4/

There it is. just add:

```
float:left;
```

to both divs.

Comment: Thanks but how can I do to have my 2 blocks centered?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#block1
{
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
#block2
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    margin-left:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#block2
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 180px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="block1" style="float:left;">
        Merci d'avoir utilisé notre plateforme...
    </div>

    <div id="block2" style="float:right;">
        Nos bureaux sont ouverts du lundi au vendredi de 9h00 à 17h00
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

try like this.........u get answer